# .NET Core 3.1 Controller receiving CSV

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I cannot get an Endpoint to receive media-type text/csv.

I have a .Net Core 3.1 API app that needs to have an endpoint that receives a CSV.  I figured adding this would be fine:

```
[HttpPost("CSV")]
[Consumes("text/csv")]
public async Task<IActionResult> InsertCsv([FromBody] string values)
{
    return Ok($"here is the data!\r\n{values}");
    
}
```

However, in Postman sending the request returns this error:

> {
> "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
> "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
> "status": 415,
> "traceId": "|e2e74cae-4824ee592543d555." }

With that error figured I would have to do something in the `ConfigureServices` however, I cannot find anything.  I did find you need to add for XML:

```
services.AddControllers().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Cannot figure out what do to add text/csv.

Comment: Just use `StreamReader` over `Request.Body`.

Comment: @Dai sorry, not sure what exactly you mean.  Do you mean this:  `InsertCsv([FromBody] StreamReader values)`

Comment: Rather, `return Ok($"here is the data!\r\n{new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd()}");` Leave `InsertCsv` without parameters. Note: `ReadToEnd()` might not work in certain scenarios (when synchronous I/O is checked) and you might have to use `await ReadToEndAsync()` instead

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That worked!  if you put this as the answer I will award it

Comment: btw. If the csv is uploaded from a html form, the easiest way is to use `[FromForm] IFormFile file` as parameter. The IFormFile has the all you need and even keeps the original file name.